# How to use dynamically assigned table name for binding in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I just (again) realized that I do not understand binding in WPF.
I used the following construction to bind a table to a data grid (this happens in a Window):

```
OdbcConnection con; 
... // open con 
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
// in the database we have a table named "producer"
OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from producer", con);
adapter.Fill(ds,"producer"); // (1), map the tablename in ds to "producer"
this.DataContext = ds;
...
```

and the relevant part of the XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding producer}"  // (2)
    ...// other properties
/>
```

Since this works fine I now want to generalize this code so I can use it for other tables, as well. That is I'd like to replace the fixed string `"producer"` in the lines tagged with (1) and (2) with a string variable `tableName` in (1) resp. it's content in (2). Here is where I'm stuck: how do I define this binding in (2)? I tried to make the `tableName` a property of the Window class, but in XAML I get the error that "the type converter for IEnumerable does not support conversion from a character sequence" (I translated this last statement from it's German form, so it may not match precisely the English counterpart).

Can I actually do this in XAML, or do I need to define the binding programmatically?

Comment: Do all the tables have the same structure? If they don't, your specific bindings inside the DataGrid won't work.

Either way, on the line where you do 'adapter.Fill' you have the option of specifying your own name anyhow, so leave the binding called something like "dataTable" and only change your underlying SQL query but always map the result to "dataTable".

Comment: Hmm yes, this will do the trick. Stupid me...and thank you. This is, as of now, supposed to be used for one single table at a time only. Why should this cause trouble when I use tables with different structures?